# How to reverse binary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

So I am wondering if a binary string such as:

```
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01001101 01101111 01101101 00100001
```

(Hello Mom!)
can be reversed in the way that ***ALL*** `1`s turn into `0`s and vice verca in Python 3.

Comment: That is called bitwise `xor` or `^` operator.

Comment: @AChampion: Bitwise `xor` doesn't work on a string.

Comment: @KenWhite You can just convert to `int(n, 2) ^ 0xff`.

Comment: @AChampion: Yes, I'm aware. You didn't explain that; you suggested using `^` on a string, and I pointed out that will not work.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You **cannot** edit your post to ask an additional question, especially after this one has been answered. If you now have another question, first search this site **thoroughly** to see if it's been asked and answered before. If it has not, then click the *Ask Question* button and create a new post to ask it.

Comment: @KenWhite Understood, ultimately it looks like the OP is just trying to use a `xor` translation of `'Hello Mom!'` so all the intermediate binary strings are likely to be unnecessary, e.g.: `''.join(chr(ord(c) ^ 0xff) for c in s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a="01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01001101 01101111 01101101 00100001"
a=a.replace('0','a').replace('1','0').replace('a','1')
```

You could use the replace function.

Output:

```
'10110111 10011010 10010011 10010011 10010000 11011111 10110010 10010000 10010010 11011110'
```

Comment: Nice "workaround" method without getting into actual binary operators.

Comment: Use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) to avoid any "workaround" which requires that the string be processed 3 times.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the binary string and use bitwise manipulation, e.g.:

```
In []:
x = '01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01001101 01101111 01101101 00100001'
r = [format(int(n, 2) ^ 0xff, 'b') for n in x.split()]
r

Out[]:
['10110111', '10011010', '10010011', '10010011', '10010000',
 '11011111', '10110010', '10010000', '10010010', '11011110']
```

It's simple enough to join this back up:

```
In []:
' '.join(r)

Out[]:
'10110111 10011010 10010011 10010011 10010000 11011111 10110010 10010000 10010010 11011110'
```

Comment: Can you please provide feedback if you vote down, it's helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use join with a generator, and replace the `'1'` with `'0'`s and vice versa, while keeping any character that is neither (a space in your example) unchanged:

```
string = "01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01001101 01101111 01101101 00100001"
reverse = ''.join('0' if c=='1' else ('1' if c=='0' else c) for c in string)
print(reverse)
```

Outputs:

```
10110111 10011010 10010011 10010011 10010000 11011111 10110010 10010000 10010010 11011110
```

As commented by @AChampion, you could shorten and improve the above code using:

```
string = "01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01001101 01101111 01101101 00100001"
reverse = ''.join('10'[int(c)] if c in '01' else c for c in string)
print(reverse)
```

Comment: `''.join('10'[int(c)] for c in string)` would also work.

Comment: @AChampion You're right, thanks, I included your suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) is very useful, and efficient, for this:

```
bits = '01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01001101 01101111 01101101 00100001'

table = {ord('0'): '1', ord('1'): '0'}    # '0' -> '1', '1' -> '0'
inverted_bits = bits.translate(table)
print(inverted_bits)
```

Output:

```
10110111 10011010 10010011 10010011 10010000 11011111 10110010 10010000 10010010 11011110
```

This is also handy if you wanted to apply other transformations. For example the spaces could also be removed with this translation table:

```
table = {ord('0'): '1', ord('1'): '0', ord(' '): None}
print(bits.translate(table))
```

Output:

```
10110111100110101001001110010011100100001101111110110010100100001001001011011110
```

Also, use [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.maketrans) to create the translation table:

```
>>> table = str.maketrans('01', '10')
>>> print(bits.translate(table))
10110111 10011010 10010011 10010011 10010000 11011111 10110010 10010000 10010010 11011110
```

or

```
>>> print(bits.translate(str.maketrans('01', '10', ' ')))
10110111100110101001001110010011100100001101111110110010100100001001001011011110
```